# Sql select with Null and Not Null values

Tags: sql, select, null, oracle12c, exists

I have a table like below.

[image]

I wanted to select the spec_id with language is not null. But when a spec_id has no values other than null then i wanted to select that spec_id with null value as well.
For eg. Spec_id '170470' has Language 'EN'. I wanted to select only that row with Language is not null for this spec_id. And spec_id '170464' has only Null value. So i wanted to select that row as well.

I have tried with below query but it selects only that case with NOT NULL in Language.

```
   SELECT * from temp_value w1 
    where w1.NAC_ID = 2453 
    and w1.language is not null 
    or (w1.language is null and not exists (select spec_id from temp_value w2
                                        where w2.nac_id = 2453 
                                        and spec_id  in (select spec_id from temp_value 
                                                           where nac_id = 2453 and language is not null))
         and w1.nac_id = 2453);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we can actually simplify this by using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY spec_id ORDER BY language) rn
    FROM temp_value t
)

SELECT language, value, value_id, spec_id, language_id, nac_id
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This should work because Oracle by default sorts `NULL` last.  This means that, for each group of `spec_id` records, the non `NULL` language value would float to the top, if it exists.  Only if a given `spec_id` group have no non `NULL` language records would a `NULL` record be selected.

**Edit:**

To cater to the problem where there might be two or more non `NULL` language records, with the previous logic for retaining a `NULL` only should there be no non `NULL` records, we can try:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY spec_id ORDER BY language) rn
    FROM temp_value t
)

SELECT language, value, value_id, spec_id, language_id, nac_id
FROM cte
WHERE language IS NOT NULL OR (rn = 1 AND language IS NULL);
```

Comment: HI, i tried it. this works for this case but where there are more language for one spec_id eg. for spec_id 170470 if there are two languages like EN and DE then it just selects the row 1 value.

Comment: @newintodev Sure, check the second query which I just added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just use a correlated subquery: in the subquery you refer to the table alias of the main query.

```
select * from temp_value t
where language is not null
or language is null and not exists (select 'x'
                                    from temp_value
                                    where spec_id = t.spec_id
                                    and nac_id = t.nac_id
                                    and (language is not null
                                         or value is not null
                                         or language_id is not null));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
 SELECT * from temp_value w1 
    where w1.NAC_ID = 2453 
    and w1.language is not null 
    or (w1.language is null and not exists 
           (select spec_id from temp_value w2
               where w2.nac_id = 2453 
               and w2.spec_id=w1.spec_id  
               and language is not null
            )
         );
```

or am I missing something?